# How to use keycloak with NestJS and passport?

Tags: keycloak, nestjs, passport-local, passport-jwt

I need to use keycloak in my application in nest js but as much as I'm looking for I don't know how to implement the passport strategy. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Found the `passport-keycloak-bearer` package on NPM but that uses a different syntax than NestJS with its annotations. Does anybody know if there exists a wrapper?